# Filter SQL results by highest number in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table that stores data to show on a report. Each time records are inserted into the database, another row is added except the ReportNumber row is incremented. I've been searching and can't seem to find anyone else who may have asked this. I need the stored procedure to get the latest report info (highest number in the ReportNumber row). How can I do this? Here's an example.

```
Year     Data     ReportNumber
2014     135      1
2014     135      2
2014     136      1
2014     136      2
```

When I run the report I only want to show the latest data based on the ReportNumber (2 in this case)

Comment: I think as you can tell from all the different replies, this question needs additional clarification...

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I need to return ALL rows with the highest ReportNumber, I've already selected the answer that worked. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do it:

```
select * 
  from Table
 where ReportNumber in (select max(ReportNumber) 
                          from Table)
```

Comment: This was the first answer I tried and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `order by` like

```
select * from 
report_table
order by
ReportNumber desc
```

(OR)

```
select * from 
report_table
where ReportNumber = (select max(ReportNumber) from report_table)
```

Comment: Be careful, this is not deterministic

Comment: @M.Massias, not sure what you mean by `not deterministic`? if my understanding is correct OP want the row for which reportnumber is highest.

Comment: yes, and if there are 2 with highest reportnumber (as in his example), your query won't give the same every time.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't as clear as I'd like, I need to return ALL rows with the highest ReportNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to select the row which has the max reportnumber grouped by year and data?  If so, there are a number of ways.  Here is one using the `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
    select t.year, 
        t.data, 
         t.reportnumber, 
         row_number() over (partition by year, data order by reportnumber desc) rn
    from yourtable t
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ALL rows where ReportNumber is equal to the maximum value in your table :

```
SELECT yourTable.*
FROM yourTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Max(reportNumber) as maxRep)
WHERE yourTable.ReportNumber = maxRep
```

If you want, for each value of data, to get the latest report :

```
SELECT yourTable.*
FROM yourTable
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT Data, Max(reportNumber) as maxRep 
    FROM yourTable 
    GROUP BY Data) as maxTable
ON yourTable.ReportNumber = MaxTable.maxRep
    AND yourTable.Data = MaxTable.Data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can also use `TOP` in combination with the `WITH TIES` option. This selects all records having the same (maximum, because of the ordering) ReportNumber.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ReportNumber DESC
```